# Impossible join articles to comments PHP & SQL

Tags: php, sql, web, inner-join

i'm a new web developper and I'm learning Php.
For my certificate I need to do a PHP blog using OOP MVC architecture.
So I try with someone's MVC framework and I can't join the Articles and Comments table,
Either all the comments appear under all the articles, or none appear. and article_id stays at 0, maybe the problem is there?
Can you help me guys, I'm stuck like 2 days on it.

Thank you very much,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3HY6.png and the code :

```
private $dbcomm;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->dbcomm = new Database;
        }

        public function getComm(){
            $this->dbcomm->query('SELECT *,
                                    comments.article_id as commentsId,
                                    users.created_at as userCreated,
                                    comments.created_at as commentsCreated
                                    FROM comments
                                    INNER JOIN users ON comments.user_id = users.id
                                    INNER JOIN posts ON comments.article_id = posts.id
                                    ORDER BY comments.created_at DESC');


            $results= $this->dbcomm->resultSet();

            return $results;
        }
```

Comment: Try adding where clause in query for each post as ```"where comments.article_id=".$current_article_id ```.

Comment: Thanks for you response, I try this one: `$this->dbcomm->query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comments.article_id = posts.id'); ` and this error appears : ` Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'posts.id' in 'where clause' ` Thank you Mukhtar

Comment: ```post id``` would be the variable in your php code haivng post ID in it. The variable would b concatenated with the query.

Comment: you need to add where clause in your query having all the joins which you have posted here as a question. i.e ```SELECT *,comments.article_id as commentsId,users.created_at as userCreated,comments.created_at as commentsCreated FROM comments INNER JOIN users ON comments.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN posts ON comments.article_id = posts.id WHERE comments.article_id=".$current_article_id." ORDER BY comments.created_at DESC```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried and article_id is 0 again :(, even I add an id to article_id, like article_id = 21, It doesn't appear on posts 21.

Comment: I tried this : `public function getCommByPost($id){
   $this->dbcomm->query('SELECT *,
        comments.created_at as commentsCreated,
        users.created_at as userCreated
        FROM comments 
        INNER JOIN users
        ON comments.user_id = users.id
        WHERE article_id = :id');
   $this->dbcomm->bind(':id', $id);
   $results = $this->dbcomm->resultSet();
   return $results;
  }`
And when I change article_id in mysql ( like article_id=20 for posts.id = 20 ) it's working. So I think this one is OK, I think I need to change something when I post a comm ( function? )